# Are sock puppet answer accepts retracted?

Tags: discussion, support, moderator-tools, accepted-answer, sock-puppets

A user used sock puppets to ask questions and answer with main account, then accept own answers, even if there's other answers, including ones that outscore it significantly. Self-upvotes were retracted, but self-accepts weren't, and continue to inflate answers' worth and visibility (some networks still prioritize accepts).

Moreover, the sock puppet self-accepting has since resumed.

Will self-accepts eventually be retracted? How long does this take? And are such accounts monitored for further violations?

Comment: Not being done automatically (typical oversight), there's already request from 6 years ago to do that. (so far without any response from SE)

Comment: If you notice bad behavior of user, no matter the background, please report to mods via a flag. They do not monitor accounts with past violations. (Except maybe extreme cases.)

Comment: Not exact duplicate: not all socks were deleted. Regardless, I've confirmed self-accepts were retracted (what I saw was a renewal).

Comment: If you see obvious case of sock that wasn't deleted, ordinary votes retracted, but accepts stay, should report this as a bug.